# Schedule daily function in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is there a way you can schedule a function to run daily in a Corona SDK App?

```
function DailyFunction()
    print("daily function")
end -- run this function every 24 hours
```

Answer (score 0):

A literal answer to your question would be:

```
function DailyFunction()
    print("daily function")
end -- run this function every 24 hours

timer.performWithDelay( (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24), DailyFunction )
```

but I suspect you aren't expecting the user to keep the app open all the time which this would require.

Quite a bit more complex but perhaps what you'll need to do is to schedule a local notification 24 hours in the future.  Details of how to do that can be found at http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/events/appNotification/index.html#ios

Remember that you'll need to reschedule the notification each time it fires.

Comment: users will have to have notifications enabled for the app as well.